# sapply mult column and dataframe

Tags: r

I am new to R using SPSS for many years.

my data column are.

```
"ffqnum"   "tot_wt"   "ffq_name" "foodcode" "foodname" "nut203"   "nut204"   "nut205"   "nut208"
  num       double    char        num        char      double      double     double     double
```

I use `sapply` to calculate new values for 4 column

```
ffq2 <- sapply(ffq116[, c(6:num_col)] ,function(i) i * ffq116$tot_wt)
ffq2 = data.frame(ffq2)
```

the new  dataframe have only 4 columns

```
"nut203" "nut204" "nut205" "nut208"
```

I am looking for advise how to salve the flowing task:
Is there a way using `sapply` or other method to get columns "ffqnum" "tot_wt" "ffq_name" "foodcode" "foodname" back into the calculate dataframe.
Is there a way to add a key column to the new dataframe.
I know I can use loop but can it be done using `sapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign back into the corresponding columns.

```r
ffq116[c(6:num_col)] <- sapply(ffq116[c(6:num_col)], function(i) i * ffq116$tot_wt)
```

I recognize this overwrites your version of `ffq116`, you may prefer to first copy it with `ffq2 <- ffq116` and then operate on *that* frame instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tidyverse` verbs and try the following codes:

```
library("tidyverse")
ffq2 <- ffq116 %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("nut")), .funs = ~ . * tot_wt)
```